# best way to copy an object of class in c++

Tags: c++, oop

if i have an object of class c1 suppose its name object1 and i want to make another object of the same class suppose object2 is it better to declare it like this:

```
c1 object2 = object1;
```

or use the copy constructor

```
c1 object2 = c1(object1);
```

i now that in C# it differs because in the first case it copies the reference of the object and in the second case it creates a new one, but i want to now if it is the same in c++

Comment: It makes no difference.

Comment: What did [your C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) say on the topic? Did you **any** research on your own, before asking?

Comment: `c1 object2 = object1;` uses the copy constructor.

Comment: yes i did @AlgirdasPreidžius

Comment: @baselman The existence of this question contradicts such statement. Also, you forgot to answer my first question. What did [your C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) said on this topic?

Comment: @NeilButterworth They both use the copy constructor.

Comment: Creating a new instance from an old one will use the copy constructor, regardless of whether the syntax is `T new = old;`, `T new(old);`, or `T new = T(old);`.  [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bc779fe0c36ecd4).

Comment: because doing a research includes searching in books @AlgirdasPreidžius

Comment: @JustinTime That is technically true but prior to 17 `T new = T(old)` involves a copy and a move.

Comment: thanks for helping

Comment: @NirFriedman True.  I've noticed that compilers tend to be eager to optimise it into just a copy, though, even prior to that, so I included it.

Comment: @Nir That sort of was my point.

Comment: @baselman Because you, typically, learn from books. And such a basic question, would've been, **definitely** answered there. In addition, you could type _C++ object copying_ into your favorite search engine, and you would've found the answer to this question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two forms will do exactely the same thing (copy the object). It makes no difference.

Comment: This is not strictly correct, prior to c++17. The first one only calls the copy constructor, the second calls the copy constructor and then the move constructor.